# How to search keyword using PHP DBA function

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use PHP DBA function to search a DB file with keyword just like you do search with mysql `like` statement.

I have looked up the php manual but couldn't find any function for it. Anyone got a good idea for doing it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: does berkely DB support LIKE statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `like` in DBA functions
but you can create something like this using `dba_fetch()`.
just pass throughout the whole db using this function and use regular expression `preg_match` to allow wildcard matching